# struggling to understand code written for me by my tutor, for arknoid/brickbreaker collision detection

Tags: c#, linq, collision-detection

I asked a third year student to help me detect collisions for the game, I've tried understanding the order but the last 20 or so lines don't make much sense to me, would anyone by willing to make it a bit more cleaner?

Specifically I need to understand what the code means from the keyword "Where". Any improvements that can be made to the code would be appreciated.

```
UIElement upDownBlock = MyGrid.Children.Cast<Rectangle>().Where(i => (Grid.GetRow(i) == ballRow + vely) && (Grid.GetColumn(i) == ballColumn)).FirstOrDefault();
if (upDownBlock != null)
{
    vely = -vely;
    MyGrid.Children.Remove(upDownBlock);
}
UIElement leftRightBlock = MyGrid.Children.Cast<Rectangle>().Where(i => (Grid.GetColumn(i) == ballColumn + velx) && (Grid.GetRow(i) == ballRow)).FirstOrDefault();
if (leftRightBlock != null)
{
    velx = -velx;
    MyGrid.Children.Remove(leftRightBlock);
}
```

any sort of help would be appreciated, game was created on a grid

Comment: What specifically do you need help understanding?

Comment: The UIElement conditions mainly, need to specifically understand what the code means from the keyword "where" and improvements that can be made on the code would be appreciated

Comment: You need to study up on LINQ. And your mentor needs to study good naming conventions. Basically the code in the where clause is run against the various list of rectangles, the code in th where clause validates to either true or false and the first rectangle that matches is returned, if none match a null is returned.

Comment: Theory aspect is focused on in our second year this year was purely basics and introduction. The description you gave out helped out a lot!!! everything now makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you need to learn linq and your mentor needs to use better naming.  Does this seem more understandable?

```
Rectangle upDownBlock = MyGrid.Children.Cast<Rectangle>()
                          .Where(rect => (Grid.GetRow(rect) == ballRow + vely) && 
                                         (Grid.GetColumn(rect) == ballColumn))
                         .FirstOrDefault();
if (upDownBlock != null)
{
    vely = -vely;
    MyGrid.Children.Remove((UIElement)upDownBlock);
}
```

Basically the code in the Where clause is run against the various lists of rectangles, it evaluates to either true or false and the first rectangle that matches (evaluates to true) is returned.

An improvement would be to replace the “Where” with “FirstOrDefault” in the various assignments. This does not increase performance as you might expect, lazy evaluation means that the Where clause only evaluates the items requested, and FirstOrDefault will stop asking it to evaluate items when it finds its first match.  But it makes it clearer earlier that you don’t care about the whole list of rectangles, just the first one to match your criteria aka predicate.

Comment: way better, I'll work LINQ as soon as possible, appreciate the help

Comment: @Sihle: for your future reference when you are the mentor. On the job working code barely trumps readable code, for tutoring the reverse is true. It’s better to have readable code that is slightly wrong than unreadable code that is absolutely correct. Pseudo code doesn’t even pretend to work, but it can show what needs to be done.

Comment: I'll start putting that to practice now since this is only my first year, I now know what's it like for the other person to read unreadable code